# How to send Model value as parameter while submitting @Ajax.Beginform()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using @Ajax.Beginform in my View which is tightly bound to the ViewModel.

I've  @Html.ListBoxFor inside my form. I add and delete items from the listbox using jQuery. Now what I am want to achieve is that onpress of the submit button, it should send full data present in the listbox regardless of which are selected. Currently it sends the list to controller if  I select all the item in the listbox and press submit button. But I don't want to do that. Any idea as to how to achieve this?

Can it be sent as a form parameter.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTextComponent", "LoanFilterEditor", new{ param1 = Model.listBoxItem},  new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "SUCCESS" }))
```

I try to accept the parameter in the controller like this

```
public ActionResult SaveTextComponent(TextComponentViewModel model, List<SelectListItem> list)
{
}
```

But list is null.. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this javascript to select all items at your listbox and then, send it to controller:

```
function listbox_selectall(listID, isSelect) {
    var listbox = document.getElementById(listID);
    for(var count=0; count < listbox.options.length; count++) {
        listbox.options[count].selected = isSelect;
    }
}
```

And after that, you can call the function on your form in this way:

```
<script>
function submit() {
     listbox_selectall('righthand_side_listbox_id', true);
     return true;
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return submit()">
...
</form>
```

Credits to [Viral Patel blog](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/listbox-select-all-move-left-right-up-down-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my example:

Model:

```
pulic class TextComponentViewModel {
   public int[] SelectedListItem { get; set; }
   public List<Item> ListItem { get; set; }
}

public class Item {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model TextComponentViewModel 

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTextComponent", "LoanFilterEditor", null,  new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "SUCCESS" }, new {name = "mainForm", id = "mainForm"}))
{
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedListItem , new MultiSelectList(Model.ListItem, "ID", "Name"))

  for(var i = 0; i < Model.ListItem.Count();i++ )
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListItem[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListItem[i].Name)
  } 
 <input type = "submit" id="submitButton" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveTextComponent(TextComponentViewModel model)
{

}
```

Script:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
  $("#mainForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. But I want the entire list in the listbox to be submitted even if none of the items are selected. I have done the same way as you have. It sends the items only if I select them.

Comment: You don't need to specify the name property in your `for` loop. `HiddenFor` will set that automatically.

Comment: Please see my change and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). I hope it can help you :)

Comment: @mattytommo I think it's ok :)

Comment: Thanks. But still it doesn't solve my problem. Because I add various item to the listbox using jQuery and those items don't get picked up by Model.ListItem. Now it sends only the items which were originally sent by the the controller. Can you suggest some other workaround?